# html and css in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, parsing

I am having trouble designing a solution to a complex problem. I am building a site that creates html templates including both the css files and html files. Users will be able to create multiple templates/sites.

In an attempt to create a normalized database I have a user table (id, name, email, password, etc.), a site list table (user_id, site_id, site_name, description), and the rest I am having trouble figuring out.

I am trying to develop a way to break down both the html files and css files into a database that can be used to reproduce the designed template. Constant editing and adding to the database will take place when creating/editing a template. Basically, an extremely simplified dreamweaver. Flat files may be an option as well.

Any input or suggestions on how to go about such site would be greatly appreciated such as how to break down the html and css into mysql tables/records. Im not so much looking for code, but the fundamental concepts/workings of such a site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to represent the css and html structure in the data base?

Comment: I want users to have full control over the templates, one user may have 10 elements (div, p, a, etc.) in a template, another user may have 100. Elements can be nested with no level limit. I am not sure the best way to store something like this given that changes can be made, elements can be added/removed, and css properties can be added such as background, border, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure you even want to store that content in the database?  That's going to place a heavy burden on your servers over generating them as files onto the filesystem inside the DocumentRoot and directly servable by the web server.  I can see storing the configuration options (color choices, image names, etc) in the database, but not the files themselves.

Can these websites have any content the customer wants, or are they variations on a theme?  If it's the former, then you really can't automate it much.  You can store the content in a database instead of a file, but it won't really be advantageous.

Your best bet, I think, is to look how CMS programs like WordPress/Joomla break up a page into separate include files (header, footer, left menus, right menus, etc) and use that as a model.  The customer picks a template, and each template has defined sections that can be laid out separately with different content.

Comment: The purpose of this site will be similar to a basic dreamweaver; the user will start with a blank page and begin adding elements. Content of paragraphs, lists, etc. will be included as well. The user will be able to view and download his/her template whenever they want. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the templates in text files then store settings (such as CSS attributes or images they may want) in the database. That way, you just load the template with the applied settings.

Comment: The template will be generated. For example the user will create a div element, apply some css components to the div, then possibly add a paragraph element and list elements within the div with their own css properties

Comment: If elements can be nested with no limit, you are better off storing the templates in files rather than a database, as that will make the database very slow.

Comment: One option I have looked into was a table to store the hierarchy levels of the html in a mysql table using the modified preorder tree traversal algorithm, then possibly having additional tables to store css properties. This will make it simple to add and remove elements. If flat files are used, the whole file will have to be read and stored as a string to modify, then rewrite the whole file each time a change is made. I was thinking the database option would be much faster and less work on the server but I could be wrong

Comment: You could store hierarchy levels for the basic framework of the template. But, you would still probably want to store added HTML in a file rather than in a database. Raw HTML will take up a lot of space and it would probably be faster loading from a file.

Comment: Instead of raw html, I had in mind some type of parsing or serialization (not sure which is the correct one here). The html would be broken down by element, then left and right positions for the traversal algorithm, then any attributes such as id, class, etc. This would eliminate storing text such as <>,=, etc. I guess I am trying to keep things as quick as possible; edits and changes will happen very frequently where full page loads will not. I am assuming it would be much quicker to make 100 additions to a database than make 100 changes to text files